Wrap autocompleted arguments on a new line in Flutter in VS Code
Is there a way, in VS Code, to make the autocompleted widget arguments go on a new line?
Bad:
Column(children: [])

Good:
Column(
    children: []
)

I guess it has something to do with the dart_style's formatter (?)

You can add a comma after the last argument to tell the Dart formatter that you want the argument to be split across multiple lines:
Column(
  children: [],
);

(This is something that might change in the future: https://github.com/dart-lang/dart_style/issues/1253)

It honestly doesn't work. VS Code is already putting a comma after the argument when I press Tab to select the suggested autocompletion. I tried removing it and adding it back, but nothing.

@SyncroIT In that case, it sounds like your VS Code are not using the Dart formatter for formatting your files. Have you done the following? https://docs.flutter.dev/tools/formatting#automatically-formatting-code-in-vs-code

Yes I have, I have Flutter's extension installed on VS Code.
https://youtu.be/RJ_0A3OCy5E

Doesn't work for me either. Unfortunately the dart_style formatter is not extensible, otherwise, one day, I'm sure I would be annoyed enough to extend it with this option.

@NicholasKolatsis You are most likely not using the Dart formatter in the first place if this is not working for you. You can try post your code into https://dartpad.dev/ and click "Format" to see how the code are formatted if using the builtin formatter of Dart.

@julemand101 The dart formatter is enabled by default for everyone - "dart.enableSdkFormatter": true Actually, the issue was that I had an error elsewhere and this blocked the formatter from doing it's tricks. Thank's for the tip. It works fine.
